# Resize layout with KeyboardView

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a custom keyboard for my app only, and I have a KeyboardView in a layout. If I'm just using the built in keyboard, I can make the layout "shift" up and show the controls, edit texts, etc, above the keyboard.

Is this possible to do with a KeyboardView? Can I shift up the contents of my layout so the KeyboardView doesn't overlap any controls when it's showing?

**EDIT**

I guess some people with no experience in Android put the question on hold. If you understand Android, you understand the question, but in any case, here's an example.

Say I have a layout sort of like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <EditText />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I'm just using the built-in soft keyboard I can set the adjustPan and/or adjustResize parameters in AndroidManifest.xml and when the soft keyboard shows up when I put focus on the EditText, the layout will shift up, so the edit text (and anything underneath for example) remain visible while the soft keyboard is showing.

But say I have:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <EditText />
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I create a custom keyboard xml file, and bind it to my KeyboardView, and show it when the edit text is focused. It is not an installable InputMethodService keyboard, but a specific keyboard for my activity only. Unfortunately the KeyboardView will now overlap the edit text, and any other controls. The adjustPan and/or adjustResize doesn't apply. So is there a simple, easy solution to getting the same behavior as the default soft keyboard, ie shifting the rest of the controls up when it becomes visible?

One person indicated I would probably have to do the shifting myself, and that seems likely. But I was hoping for a simpler solution, specific to the KeyboardView.

**NOTE** If you haven't used a KeyboardView before, then don't reply. This is specific to the KeyboardView. If you haven't used a KeyboardView, don't put a question on hold which specifically deals with that widget.

Comment: You would likely have to handle resizing of the layout you want to "shift" by yourself.

Comment: Thanks zgc7009. I have a solution. If anyone would like it, feel free to email me. If Android questions are going to be modded by students and imbeciles with no Android experience, then I don't see the point in sharing anything here. If you don't understand, then admit ignorance and let the question be. zgc7009 didn't have a problem.

Comment: Please post the answer if you have one, I am dealing with the same problem.